# CS-Cart The transaction was not sent to the host because of a duplicate order id

Tags: php, payment-gateway, cs-cart

I'm using Menoris payment processor on CS-Cart v 4.3.9, a while ago this error has become more frequent "Payment processor response: The transaction was not sent to the host because of a duplicate order id".

I don't understand why is it happening, so I don't know where to look, I have tried to trigger the error myself but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Check you table **cscart_orders** and have a look at those **ID**s.

I dont think you've reched the maximum limit of mysql entries in cscart_order to be duplicate (**16777215** - is the maximum value for the field with the integer type).

In my opinion the problem is where you send data, consider to ask them for that.

Check this too: http://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/45830-issue-with-order-id/

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code and create an unique order id for each time a customer try to pay the order, something like

ex: 12345_1
where order_id = 12345 and 1 order_repaid value

you can check how 2checkout payment gateway is doing for example ;) `app/payments/2checkout.php`

```
...
$cart_order_id = ($order_info['repaid']) ? ($order_id .'_'. $order_info['repaid']) : $order_id;
...
```

if Monoris doesn't accept for order_id to be string than you will need to generate and unique order_id for each time customer try to buy and attach to order_id in this way on payment return you will be able to get the real order_id and compete the payment

*[duplicate order id] - issue is happening when a customer goes to Monoris payment page and customer click cancel or get back to website and after that he goes again to pay the order

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers, i have managed to solve this by adding a time stamp next to the order id

```
'order_id' => $processor_data['processor_params']['order_prefix'] . $order_info['order_id'] .'_'. date("G:i:s"),
```